# BAD Request 400 consume multipart/form-data jersey clientresponse java

Tags: java, http, jersey, multipartform-data, bad-request

I need consume a service, the file is a excel.
But  when I execute the consume the response is this "returned a response status of 400 Bad Request"

```
String authString = name + ":" + password;
Client restClient = Client.create();
String authStringEnc = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authString.getBytes());
// the file to upload, represented as FileDataBodyPart
FileDataBodyPart fileDataBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", new File(file),
        MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
// fileDataBodyPart.setContentDisposition(FormDataContentDisposition.name("file").fileName(file).build());

FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
multiPart.field("spId", idServicio, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart);
multiPart.setMediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(url);
ClientResponse resp = webResource.header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
        .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data").post(ClientResponse.class, multiPart);

String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);
System.out.print(output);
return resp;
```

Comment: Check the request body ( if you're sending every required input to the server). Use Rest clients like Postman or Chrome ARC to see if you are getting anything back from the service.

Comment: 400 Bad request may be because you are not sending a proper request body. It can also occur you are sending character set which its unable to understand, So you can add  .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;;charset=UTF-8").

Comment: I put a proxy and I use the Rest client "insomnia" and it works for me by insomnia.  I saw all the same. I typed the requests of both parties.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I can not resolve the mistake.
I had that use other client, apache Httpcomponents.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I put a proxy and I use the Rest client "insomnia" and it works for me by insomnia.
This is the request that sent it:

1. INSOMNIA

   ```
   POST /conf/configuration/distribution-files/service HTTP/1.1
   Authorization: Basic aW1wbGluZWE6SU1QTElORUE=
   User-Agent: insomnia/7.0.6
   Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY
   Accept: */*
   Content-Length: 5872
   Connection: close

   --X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myspprueba.xls"
   Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

   --X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="spId"

   5823
   ```
2. This is the request that at the moment i am failing

   ```
   POST /conf/configuration/distribution-files/service HTTP/1.1
   Authorization: Basic aW1wbGluZWE6SU1QTElORUE=
   Accept: */*
   Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary_1_2104028992_1577117786190
   MIME-Version: 1.0
   User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_211
   Connection: close
   Content-Length: 5994

   --Boundary_1_2104028992_1577117786190
   Content-Type: text/plain
   Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="myspprueba.xls"; modification-date="Thu, 19 Dec 2019 15:52:46 GMT"; size=5632; name="file"
   ```